# PHP mysql usage of FIND IN SET to search column values

Tags: php, mysql

here is my db  table "lessons"

[image]
When ur adding data with multiple age groups and countries i want to check whether its already exists on db

example name cannot be duplicate for same country + age comibination

if name = "sw" user cannot added country 1 or 4 or 5 or 3 for age 2 again

## EDIT

```
$age1 = explode(",", $age);
$country1 = explode(",", $country);

foreach($age1 as $ages)
{
    foreach($country1 as $country2)
    {
        $where = "find_in_set( $country2,`country`) <> 0 AND find_in_set( $ages,`age`) <> 0 AND `name` = '" . $name . "'";
    }

}
```

please check the below outcomes...

```
 var_dump($age);exit;

string '2,1' (length=3)

var_dump($country);exit;

string '1,4,2,3' (length=7)

 var_dump$country1

array (size=2)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
```

var_dump($age1);exit;

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '4' (length=1)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
  3 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Comment: the $country2 return INT or CHAR(String) ?

Comment: its return as INT @Gopal

Comment: Storing values in a csv Format is no good database design

Comment: please give example exact value in $country2 and country column

Comment: Hi, this is more of a tip to help you solve similar problems, rather than a direct answer.

Usually, you want to design the database to enforce these restrictions for you, which means you should alter your database design for the best result.

In relational databases, you want each field to only contain atomic data, ie data that cannot be broken down to smaller parts.

You should read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization it is need to know when working with relational databases!

Comment: Hope you understand my notation, this is an example of how you could design your database to automaticly enforce the restrictions you want:

`lessons( music_lesson_id, name, mp3_url ) primary_key(music_lesson_id)
lesson_country( music_lesson_id (foreign key for 'lessons'), country (potential foreign key to a 'country' table) ) primary_key(music_lesson_id, country)
lesson_age( music_lesson_id (foreign key for 'lessons'), age (potential foreign key to a 'age' table) ) primary_key(music_lesson_id, age)`

sorry about the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Here You used $where same variable two time, here no use of it.

```
$where = $country." IN  country AND ".$age." IN age";
$this->db->select("music_lessons","*",$where);
$res = $this->db->getResult();
```

return the result num of rows

Comment: i found that this query works for me SELECT * FROM `music_lessons` WHERE find_in_set('5',`country`) <> 0 AND find_in_set('2',`age`) <> 0 AND `name` = "sw"

Comment: but the problem is how can i proceed this with php

Comment: and sometime im getting multiple values for country and age therefroe i have to put this inside foreach loop . pls advice

Comment: See find_in_set have check single value in set of value. So use IN Function. SELECT * FROM music_lessons WHERE country IN ('$country') AND age IN ('$age');

Comment: my i still coudnt solve it... i have update my question . Can u check the section below EDIT ..  i have put the code which i tried and the vardump out put of some values

Comment: no need to use foreach function. just use this query SELECT * FROM music_lessons WHERE country IN ('$country') AND age IN ('$age');

Comment: but im getting multiple values for country and age fields ? is it ok

Comment: yeah this will work. the query like this only SELECT * FROM music_lessons WHERE country IN ('1,2,3,4') AND age IN ('11,55,22,33,56');